# How to ensure visibility of objects passed to an already running thread through an anonymous runnable object

Tags: java, thread-safety, visibility, runnable, anonymous

I have been reading about concurrency in Java and I understand how synchronization can be used to ensure mutually exclusive access and guaranteed visibility when objects are accessed through the same sort of path, e.g. two threads both access an object stored in the same data structure.

However, I am having trouble getting my head round how to ensure visibility of an object from a secondary thread through an an anonymous runnable, as the object is no longer being accessed by the two threads in the same context.

Say I have an executor class like the following where objects from other threads (e.g. Thread 1) can call execute(), sending with it a new task to be executed by the executor thread (Thread 2).

```
public class BasicExecutor extends Thread {

private final Object monitor = new Object();
private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable> tasks = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
private boolean running = false;

public void execute(Runnable task) {
    tasks.add(task);

    synchronized (monitor) {
        if(!running) {
            monitor.notify();
        }
    }
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
            while(tasks.isEmpty()) {
                synchronized (monitor) {
                    running = false;
                    monitor.wait();
                    running = true;
                }
            }

            tasks.remove().run();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Executor was interrupted");
    }
}
}
```

Assume this executor has been running since the start of the program but can wait() until being notified of new tasks to be run.

If I were to instantiate a new object on Thread 1 and do some things with it, then send it to the executor through an anonymous runnable like as follows:

```
final Person p = new Person("Jim");
p.setName("Rob");
p.setItem(new Shovel(ShovelType.SILVER));

executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // read some information from p
        // do some stuff with that information
    }
});
```

I assume the changes to the Person object are not guaranteed to be visible by Thread 2 when it executes, because Thread 2 started running a long time ago so there is no happens-before behaviour with creating the thread.

Firstly, is my assumption correct? And secondly, how would one go about ensuring that any changes to object in Thread 1 were visible to Thread 2? And what about changes to its child element - the shovel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you are correct.
2. Use `volatile` or `Atomic`

Comment: So I should first assign Person 'p' to `volatile Person pInRunnable = p` inside the Runnable and then use that? And would this refresh the object's state - i.e. member variables - or just its address in memory?

Comment: no, you should make member variables volatile too. Read about volatile keyword:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: I think I might be being stupid here but what if I don't have access to the class implementation? Is there no way to wrap around it to make it safe?

Comment: then make variable volatile, and wrap all mutations with synchronized blocks or methods.